# Extract characters within brackets "[" and "]" including brackets

Tags: regex, r, split, bioinformatics

I have a character string like this:

```
GATATATGGCACAGCAGTTGGATCCTTGAATGTCC[A/C]AGGTATATGTTATAGAAGCCTCGCAATTGTGTGTT
```

I realize that I can use substing for this particular case. However, the position of the `[X/Y]` differs among strings and the content between the brackets varies in length.

I would like to extract the `[X/Y]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stringr` is useful for these types of operations,

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, '\\[.*\\]')
#[1] "[A/C]"
```

or `str_extract_all` if you have more than one patterns in your strings

Answer (score 4):

We can use `bracketXtract` from `qdap`

```
library(qdap)
unname(bracketXtract(dat, "square", with = TRUE))
#[1] "[A/C]"
```

---

Or using `base R`

1. **gsub**

   ```
   gsub("^[^[]+|[^]]+$", '', dat)
   #[1] "[A/C]"
   ```
2. **strsplit**

   ```
   strsplit(dat, "[^[]+(?=\\[)|(?<=])[^]]+", perl=TRUE)[[1]][2]
   #[1] "[A/C]"
   ```

#### data

```
dat <- "GATATATGGCACAGCAGTTGGATCCTTGAATGTCC[A/C]AGGTATATGTTATAGAAGCCTCGCAATTGTGTGTT"
```

Answer (score 2):

provided that there's only 1 pair of "[]" per string, use grepexpr:

```
dat<-c("GATATATGGCACAGCAGTTGGATCCTTGAATGTCC[A/C]AGGTATATGTTATAGAAGCCTCGCAATTGTGTGTT")
substring(dat, gregexpr("\\[", dat), gregexpr("\\]", dat))
```